# How to save 2 arrays in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have two input box in a row one for style id and other for style name. but these boxes can be added dynamically to form. So can i say save these two array to code igniter db.

```
<table>
<tr>
  <td><input type="text" name="key[]" placeholder="Style ID"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="value[]" placeholder="style Name"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td><input type="text" name="key[]" placeholder="Style ID"></td>
  <td><input type="text" name="value[]" placeholder="style Name"></td>
</tr>

</table>
```

My Table structure is like

> u_id  | Style_id  | style_name

How can i save them to db?

Comment: serialize it or make it comma seprated

Comment: Can you give me an example ?

Comment: you can use `array_combine($arr1,$arr2);`... the result will be an associative array... then you can use `insert_batch()`...

Comment: @SamTengWong thanks :)

Comment: does it work? no problem... glad to help you.. =) happy coding!!